# Custom data loader is returning list in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to get 3 batches of images from 3 different folders. I have written custom data loader in pytorch. but it is returning list that has all the batches instead of single batch at a time.(running in google colab)

```
#custom data loader
class set(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataset_input, dataset_expertA, dataset_expertB):
        self.dataset1 = dataset_input
        self.dataset2 = dataset_expertA
        self.dataset3 = dataset_expertB

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x1 = self.dataset1[index]
        x2 = self.dataset2[index]
        x3 = self.dataset3[index]

        return x1, x2, x3

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataset1)

input_path = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/project/input/"

dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root= input_path, transform=transforms.Compose([
                               transforms.Resize([64,64]),
                               transforms.ToTensor(),
                               transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
                               ]))

expertA_path = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/project/expertA/"

datasetA = datasets.ImageFolder(root= expertA_path, transform=transforms.Compose([
                               transforms.Resize([64,64]),
                               transforms.ToTensor(),
                               transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
                               ]))


expertB_path = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/project/expertB/"

datasetB = datasets.ImageFolder(root= expertB_path, transform=transforms.Compose([
                               transforms.Resize([64,64]),
                               transforms.ToTensor(),
                               transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
                               ]))


data = set(dataset, datasetA, datasetB)
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(data, batch_size=64,
                                         shuffle=True, num_workers=2)


for i, (inp, expA, expB) in enumerate(dataloader):

  print(inp.shape)
  break
```

this prints error that inp is list and when i print(inp[0].shape) i get proper shape i think inp contains all batches ie inp[0], inp[1]...

what mistake am i doing in data loader code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`datasets.ImageFolder`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/datasets.html#torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder) returns a tuple of *(image, label)*, hence `inp` is also a tuple, where `inp[0]` are the images and `inp[1]` their corresponding labels. The same applies to `expA` and `expB`.

If you only want the images without the labels, you can ignore the labels and just return the images when accessing the data in your custom dataset:

```py
def __getitem__(self, index):
    image1, label1 = self.dataset1[index]
    image2, label2 = self.dataset2[index]
    image3, label3 = self.dataset3[index]

    return image1, image2, image3
```